# Why do Americans and Canadians pronounce "t" with flap [ɾ] in unstressed syllables in English?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, pronunciation, accent

Most Americans and Canadians pronounce "t" with flap [ɾ] in unstressed syllables. Why?

Comment: Why not? You make it sound like "t" is a thing and these don't count. This is misleading because it isn’t how phonology works.

Comment: @tchrist, I can't say I read that tone in the question. Maybe an answer involving lenition or phonological rules would be better than "Why not?"

Comment: @LukeSawczak lenition is a description, not an explanation of cause.

Comment: @Mitch Indeed, it wouldn't be a one-word answer, but something like "consonants in an intervocalic position tend to undergo lenition, of which this is one form..." In any case, there's clearly nothing in the question to suggest a value judgement. It's a neutrally worded statement of fact and then the valid and on-topic question of why this is the case...

Answer (score 6):

This is a common phonological process called "lenition", from the Latin for "weakening".

There are various causes posited for this, but the simplest can be summarized as *language speakers are lazy*: we will generally use the least amount of articulatory "effort" to make ourselves understood. Producing a [ɾ] takes less "effort" (tongue and mouth movement) than producing a [t], so that's what we tend to do.

Comment: This makes sense, but brings up the question as to why doesn't it always happen then? Why do BrE speakers still aspirate the t in 'water'? Why haven't the palatalized consonants (those with a jod following) all converted to an affricate (eg 'ty' -> 'tch')?

Comment: @Mitch Mostly because this is a gross oversimplification that ignores all the actual details :P but in this super-simplified model I'd say they haven't had enough time to develop that change yet.

Comment: Draconis, I only push the question because I've always wondered it myself. And I expect the real answer is that everything eventually lenides or palatalizes, or unstressed syllables drop or inflections accrete, and then the reason why all languages don't just devolve into inarticulate mumbling is that _other_ processes (of laziness) introduce stops and analytic particles.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, no, not meaning to dismiss your question at all! It just goes beyond the level of detail that my oversimplified model is capable of handling.

Answer (score 5):

The explanation for flapping, which takes place between vowels within the stress foot, has to do with the general phonetic timing of English segments, and it is a consequence of factors that shorten /t/ in that position. It has been observed that there is a tendency for segment duration to be influenced by whether the stress foot has 1 syllable versus 2, so that the vowel [i] in "seam" is longer than in "Simi" (assuming you use [i] and not [ɪ] in that word). Consonants are likewise subject to this effect. In addition, as we know, voiceless consonants are aspirated in syllable-initial foot-initial position. The combined effect of these two factors is that in words like "ha*pp*y", "lu*ck*y", the stops are shortest, compared to "a*pp*eal", "a*c*oustic".

Flapping is the result of pushing this consonant-shortening tendency a bit further, whereby in order articulate the consonant within a very short window of time, you have to throw the active articulator at the passive one (tone to alveolar ridge). This is relatively easy to do with the tongue tip, doable with the tongue body (velars can flap), and somewhat doable with labials - the reasons have to do with the mass of the articulators and the nature of articulatory control (the human tongue tip is a serious marvel). North American (and NZ) English are at the stage with alveolars flap; analogous flapping in Efik, Ibibio and numerous related languages down to NW Congo extends to labials and velars.

It is not clear what exactly pushed NA English that bit further in shortening /t/ in food-medial position. Perhaps there have been some revealing cross-dialectal studies of vowel and consonant durations in the "happy" context, which would fill in some of the missing information about this shortening trend.